# automaticSize CollectionView Crash on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios10

When i use collection cell automatic size, The app crashes on iOS 10.

```
layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

Here his the crash log.

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout internal error'
```

Why is this happening  knowing that automaticSize is available in iOS 10 ?